# How to add an event to a calendar SILENTLY in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calendar, google-calendar-api

I read a previous question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709477/how-to-add-calendar-events-to-default-calendar-silently-without-intent-in-andr), but it didn't quite answer mine.
I am trying to do something as simple as pressing a button and entering an event, but program keeps on crashing. My code is:

```
package com.example.events;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.events.R;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Perform action on click
            addCalendarEvent();
        }

    });

}

public void addCalendarEvent() {

    long calID = 1;
    long startMillis = 0;
    long endMillis = 0;
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2015, 8, 9, 7, 30);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2015, 8, 9, 8, 45);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/New_York");
    Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
   }
  }
```

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.events" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

So, basically what I am trying to do is press that button and add an event to the calendar without prompting the user to enter any details. Any help would be appreciated. 
This is the stack trace for errors:

```
08-29 18:14:44.108  13218-13218/com.example.events E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
08-29 18:14:44.118  13218-13218/com.example.events E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.example.events [ userId:0 | appId:10255 ]
08-29 18:14:52.106  13218-13218/com.example.events E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.events, PID: 13218
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2 from ProcessRecord{44f66d78 13218:com.example.events/u0a255} (pid=13218, uid=10255) requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR or android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4843)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:2718)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:1390)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1196)
        at com.example.events.MainActivity.addCalendarEvent(MainActivity.java:60)
        at com.example.events.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4753)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19562)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add your stack trace please

Comment: @Zar How do I do so? You want a screentshot?

Comment: Just copy and paste it then format it as code.

Comment: @Zar please let me know if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Now you can see your problem, you need to add the permissions from the error message to your manifest. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application Let me know if it solves your problem and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Zar Thanks for the reference it helped. The problem wasn't that I wasn't including the permissions, it was that I was putting them inside of the application tag when they need to be outside of the application tag. Thanks man, appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll add it as an answer that you can accept

Comment: @Zar Of course, you answered my question one way or another! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace says that you are missing permissions. You need to add the permissions mentioned in the stack trace to your Android manifest. See this:  [How to add manifest permission to android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application)